# How to hide the cfgrid default bottom toolbar?

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid, coldfusion-2018

As coldfusion is upgraded for my current application. The earlier code for extjs isn't working anymore

Could you suggest the latest version for the below implementations?

```
var grid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('mainGrid');
grid.getBottomToolbar().hide();
```

this doesnt hide the default toolbar that appears with cfgrid. Tried adding a  `xtype: 'pagingtoolbar'`, to the grid and `renderTo :grid.bbar` , where `grid.bbar` is null in the newest version.

Also

```
e.grid.colModel.config[e.column].editor.selectOnFocus = true;
```

while adding a listener function the above code isn't working

Also

```
grid.syncSize();//Sync to size up everything properly again
```

what shall be used instead here?

Comment: Ah the joys of using Adobe's UI components.. Haven't used cfgrid in ages, but .. did you also try [ColdFusion.Grid.hideBottomToolbar(Id)](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/ajax-javascript-functions/coldfusion-autosuggest-getautosuggestobject/coldfusion-grid-hidebottomtoolbar.html)

Comment: Seems like this worked to hide the default  cfgrid bottom toolbar.

Comment: What Attributes did you define the <cfgrid> tag with?

Comment: Also, SO prefers one question per thread, so you might want to break up the multiple questions b) Since a lot of the UI stuff is deprecated (and was volatile to begin with) might consider switching to an external js lib for things like grids, to avoid it breaking when you upgrade CF